# How to user SQL two table field.? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want to access two table field but I cant get success. Here is my little code. please check that. I want to access `Analysis.Right` and `tabl3.right`.
I am printing its with foreach loop. like `$res['Right']` of Analysis and `$res['right']` of tabl3. when I try to print this it's show me error

> `Undefind index Right`.

any one can help me

```
$qry = "select Analysis.Q_Id, tabl3.Q_Id, Analysis.Right, tabl3.right  from tabl3 INNER JOIN Analysis ON Analysis.Q_Id = tabl3.Q_Id where Analysis.Q_Id = 3";
```

please help..

Comment: Please show me all part of your code. Which driver do you use ?

Comment: use column name with also table name eg. $res['Analysis.Right'] of Analysis and $res['tabl3.right'] of tabl3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have tow column with right name related  to different  table  so there is not a column name right but 'Analysis.Right ' or 'tabl3.right'

or you can assign an alias  for set the column name equalt to Right where you need .. eg:

```
  $qry = "select 
                Analysis.Q_Id
              , tabl3.Q_Id
              , Analysis.Right as Right
              , tabl3.right  as Right_t3
          from tabl3 
          INNER JOIN Analysis ON Analysis.Q_Id = tabl3.Q_Id where Analysis.Q_Id = 3";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result set has columns with the same name.  Give them different names:

```
select t3.Q_Id, a.Right as a_right, t3.right as t3_right
from tabl3  t3 inner join
      Analysis a
      on a.Q_Id = t3.Q_Id
where a.Q_Id = 3;
```

When you look for the names in your code, look for `a_right` and `t3_right`.

Note that you don't need to return `Q_Id` twice.  The `ON` clause guarantees that the values are the same.